# How to make a NSTextField added to a NSView Draggable

Tags: events, mouseevent, nsview, nsevent

Let me elaborate the steps i am doing

1. Create Mac 10.9 Project
2. Drag a CustomView (Let's call it myView) to the .xib
3. Drag a NSButton to the .xib but out side the CustomView
4. Now programatically (using a other class) i add a NSTextField to the CustomView when the button is clicked by this code

   NSTextField *textField  = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
   [textField setBezeled:NO];
   [textField setEditable:NO];
   [textField setSelectable:NO];
   [textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20]];
   [textField setStringValue:@"Hello World!"];
   int textWidth = textField.fittingSize.width;
   int textHeight = textField.fittingSize.height;
   [textField setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, textWidth, textHeight)];
   [myView addSubview:textField];
5. Now i see that the TestField is added to myView
6. All i want is the user can drag the textField movable inside myView

i added the following code

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}
```

But the  NSLog is not getting shown

How do i make the NSTextField draggable?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Because mouse-moved events occur so frequently that they can
>   quickly flood the event-dispatch machinery, an NSWindow object by
>   default does not receive them from the global NSApplication object.
>   However, you can specifically request these events by sending the
>   NSWindow object an setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents: message with an
>   argument of YES.

From [Apple Docset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html)